# Adding a form input breaks form

Tags: html, forms

Right now I have a form with one input and one textarea, and I am trying to add an input, however when I do it causes the form to not submit, I am submitting by hitting the enter key and not using a button.

Current code:

```html
<form method="POST">
Suggestion Subject: <input class="login-input" name="subject"><br> 
Suggestion: 
<textarea class="login-input" rows="8" name="suggestion"></textarea><br>
Username: 
<input class="login-input" type="text" name="name"><br>
Hit the Enter key to submit your suggestion
</form>
```

When I add the `Suggestion Subject` input, it can no longer be submitted.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of a HTML form with a single input field is to submit the form on pressing enter on that field. Once you add more text inputs, pressing enter will no longer submit the form. To submit the form via enter, you'll need to add a submit button. If you don't want to see the button you can hide it.

Comment: `display:none` on a submit button should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4sk3tL1s/1/. Or you could move it off screen with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Add type="text" to your subject field, like so:

```
<input class="login-input" type="text" name="subject">
```

and add a submit button like so (this will hide in all browsers):

```
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
```

Comment: Is that your only code?  Show me the rest of your code?

Comment: That is my only code, aside from some PHP which has no effect on it

Comment: So, you don't have this wrapped in HTML and body tags?

Comment: I do not, no. I think that has no impact though, since the other answer explained it.

Comment: See updated answer, I found your ultimate solution which hides the submit button in all browsers since it is required.  You should still add type=text on your input field.